# Want an iPhone / iPad / iOS Webpage that is 100% width/height

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, ios, webkit

I'm trying to get a site that is simply 100% of the possible width/height of a device, after scrolling down far enough to get rid of the address bar.  Hopefully that makes sense?

I just need the simple dimensions so I can scroll the device to 0,0 and see as much of my page as possible.  e.g. simply 320x400 (320 width, 400 might = height - title bar - footer)

The reason for this is that I'm putting a single DIV on a page that is a "viewport" into content that moves around, think google maps.  I just want this div to fill all available space.

The problem is that I can't seem to detect the available window height.  I always seem to get the screen size - the title bar - the address bar - optional debug bar - footer.  How do I detect the "largest possible size"?

Answer (score 1):

Put `html,body` with `height:100%;` and the `div` as `position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;` and then you dont need the exact width/height of the viewport, the `div` will already use the maximum possible space.

But if you still want to detect, jQuery got the `$(element_you_want).width()` and `.height()` also that might do the trick. Try with document or only body (with 100% height)

Comment: @Sparky672 thanks for editing, i posted from Stackoverflow mobile in my iPhone, pain in the ass to format, although i just logged to edit but seems you made it already =)

Comment: Yes, I can't find the ( ` ) key in the iOS.

Comment: actually it won't be -- it'll be the height of the window - the height of the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using javascript, try alerting: 'innerWidth';

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html